# Is there a simple way to map a single URL to another URL in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have a working ASP.NET MVC application to which I would like to add a very simple URL which I would like to be redirected to another URL, without the Controller part of the path in it.

I.e. I want to be able to tell people to go to mySite.org/Hello and have it direct them to mySite.org/Whatever/WhateverElse?myfun=9, or whatever.

So I added a method in PublicController that redirects Hello to whatever, which works, except it requires me to tell people to go to mySite.org/**PUBLIC**/Hello, and we'd like to not have the extra word "public" in there.

Hours of confusing study later, I see that I could perhaps add a line in Global.asax.cs such as: routes.MapRoute(name: "Hello", url: "Public/Whatever"); ... or something... but that actually changes the way everything gets routed, and after trying various syntactical variations, nothing has seemed to just change one basic address to map to another basic address.

Is there a simple way to get mySite.org/Hello to map to another URL, without the virtual subdirectory for the public controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom route (it would need to be the first route in the table)

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Hello",
  url: "Hello",
  defaults: new { controller = "Whatever", action = "WhateverElse" }
);
```

then `/Hello` will redirect to `/Whatever/WhateverElse`

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much! I was so burnt out trying to figure out what was supposed to go where! This works. (I can/will mark accepted in 5 mins.)